# Azure - no access to VMs behind a internet facing standard Load Balancer

Tags: azure, high-availability, azure-load-balancer

SETUP:
I have 2 Ubuntu VMs sitting behind an internet facing standard load balancer. LB is zone redundant, 2 VMs are set up as HA in zones 1 and 2. 
VMs are spun up with a Virtual Machine Scale Set, and entire infrastructure is deployed with Terraform.

Applications running on containers in VMs are exposed on port 5050.
Inbound rules are set to allow traffic on port 80, 5050. 
Vms are in the LB backend pool.

PROBLEM:
When VMs are up and running, I access the console the VMs are unable to connect to Ubuntu repo or any external package for download.
Deleting and scaling out VMs - same issue.

[image: Load balancer rules]
Load balancer rules

[image: Load balancer probe]
Load balancer health probe

However, when I delete the LB rules and Lb-probe, and recreate them, I immediately am able to download packages from ubuntu repo or any other external link. 
I also deleted one VM and scaled out new a VM(after recreating lb rules and probe) and ubuntu packages, and docker packages install successfully.

This is driving me crazy, has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this issue in the same scenario when I deploy the entire infrastructure via the Azure portal.

According to [control outbound connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview#control-outbound-connectivity) for Standard Load Balancer:

> If you want to establish outbound connectivity to a destination
> outside of your virtual network, you have two options:
>
> - assign a Standard SKU public IP address as an Instance-Level Public IP address to the virtual machine resource or
> - place the virtual machine resource in the backend pool of a public Standard Load Balancer.
>
> Both will allow outbound connectivity from the virtual network to outside of the virtual > network.

So, this issue may happen due to the load balancer rules that have not taken effect on the initial time or not got configuration correctly or the public-facing load-balancing frontend IP has not got provisioned. Or, you may check if there is any firewall or restriction on outbound traffic from your vmss instance.

When I have provisioned these resources. I have to associate an NSG that whitelist the allowed traffic to the subnet of VMSS instances. This will trigger Standard LB to begin to receive the incoming traffic. Also, I have changed the Upgrade policy to `automatic`.

[image]

Hope this information could help you.

Comment: I have the 2 options configured. And there are no firewall rules restrictions. NSG already whitelists the traffic to VMSS instance subnet.
I'll look over the NSG one more time.

Comment: How do you reproduce this issue? When you recreate the LB rule and probe, are they the same as the initial configuration?

Comment: I manually delete the LB rule and probe, then recreate them with the same initial configuration.

Comment: Do you ensure 100% reproduce this issue, when the LB initial configuration, the VMSS instance can not go out to the internet? another suggestion is to create them via the Azure portal, compare to the configuration when you create them via terraform.

Comment: I had the VMSS created manually and it created an LB, and NAT pool. And this seemed to work. Apparently, the LB needs to be created after the VMSS is created. Still a little confusing...I am going to add these changes to my terraform config.

Comment: I don't think the LB have to create after the VMSS is created. This issue might be a issue in your terraform configuration. How is the issue going?

Comment: I also interested in this question. If you find a better solution, please share it or accept this to close your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Once I added a load balancing rule, my VMs had internet access.